# How to pass a dymamic variable inside a method in javascript?

Tags: javascript, methods

I am building a function to reverse a string but for unknown reasons to me and since I am very new to javascript (3 days only) I can not figure it out or it is possible that I have not grasped one or two concepts with the language.

Basically, I determine the length of the string which I use for the loop. After that, I try to use the same loop variable in the slice method to run thru the string from the right to left, 1 character at a time.

So far, I know that the loop is working just fine but I get no values from `phrase.slice(i,1)` but if I substitute `i` by a real number it works.

I think that I have a conceptual problem here and dynamic variables cannot be assigned to methods. I know this can be achieved using other methods but I would like to know why is this failing when it makes all the sense to me.

```
function reverseWords(phrase) {

  var build_reverse_word;

  for (let i = phrase.length ; i > 0 ; i--) {

    console.log(i); //This is just to verify that my loop is working

    build_reverse_word = phrase.slice(i,1);

    build_reverse_word = build_reverse_word + build_reverse_word;
  }

  return build_reverse_word;
}

let reverse_word_result = reverseWords("Dogs are Great Animals");

console.log(reverse_word_result);
```

What I am trying to achieve is to reverse the string backward. Thank you for your support.

Answer (score 3):

The [`.slice`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/slice) method takes in 2 arguments. `begin` and `end`. You want to extract just one letter on every iteration. But in your case the passed in arguments are not proper.

```js
function reverseWords(phrase) {

  let build_reverse_word = '';

  for (let i = phrase.length; i > 0; i--) {

    let extracted_letter = phrase.slice(i - 1, i);

    build_reverse_word = build_reverse_word + extracted_letter;
  }
  return build_reverse_word;
}

let reverse_word_result = reverseWords("Dogs are Great Animals");

console.log(reverse_word_result);
```

One more way you can go around it by avoiding the loop is to use a combination of `split` and `reverse` methods.

```js
function reverseWords(phrase) {

  // split into array
  let phraseArray = phrase.split('');
  // reverse the array contents
  phraseArray.reverse();
  // return by joining the array
  return phraseArray.join('');
}

let reverse_word_result = reverseWords("Dogs are Great Animals");

console.log(reverse_word_result);
```

Answer (score 0):

your problem is that you are using the `slice()` method. The slice method is defined as such `list.slice(startIndex,endIndex)`. Since, your code makes it such that the `endIndex` is always 1, JS is trying to find a word which starts at a high number, say `21` to a low number `1` which will never work. All slices must have an endIndex > startIndex. Thus, your code should look like this.

```js
function reverseWords(phrase) {

     var build_reverse_word;

     for (let i = phrase.length ; i > 0 ; i--) {

        console.log(i); //This is just to verify that my loop is working

        build_reverse_word = phrase.slice(i-1,i);
        console.log(build_reverse_word)
        build_reverse_word = build_reverse_word + build_reverse_word;
     }
return build_reverse_word;
}

let reverse_word_result = reverseWords("Dogs are Great Animals");

console.log(reverse_word_result);
```

now... there are some other problems with your code, but since your new to JS, i think it would be better to have you figure that one out on your own!

Answer (score 0):

Sushanth gave you the solution to your problem! But since you're also learning the language I would like to give you a few principles on strings:

A string is an instance of the parent object `String` and one of the six *primitives*. The characters in the strings can be accessed by the bracket notation `[]` or with the method `charAt`.

That means that `charAt` or the bracket notation would've worked too and probably less confusing than using `slice`.

```js
const stringValue = "Dogs are Great Animals"; //make it a constant (it will not change)

//a string is a instance of the super String, which has methods to it like slice and toUppercase.

console.log(stringValue[1]); //get the letter at position 1 - remember JavaScript is zero based.

//use a countdown (more memory efficient and less complicated
let reversed = "";
for (let i = stringValue.length-1; i >= 0; i--)
{
  reversed += stringValue[i];//use the += as a shorthand for reversed = reversed + ...
}
console.log(reversed);
```

You can also convert the string to an array with `split` and optimize your code (not use a loop)

```js
const stringValue = "Dogs are great animals";
let reversed = "";

//We can use the split method to turn the string into an array
reversed = stringValue.split("");
reversed = reversed.reverse(); // now the array can be reversed
console.log(reversed.join("")); //we use join to glue the string back together.
```

of course these can be combined: 
And put some error detection in it.

```js
function reverseWords(phrase) {
  //test if phrase is string
  if (Object.prototype.toString.call(phrase) === "[object String]") {
    return phrase.split("").reverse().join("");
  }
  else
  {
    return "Error: object is not a string"; //return error
  }
}

let reverse_word_result = reverseWords("Dogs are Great Animals");

console.log(reverse_word_result);
```